# EF Core - Shared Primary Key Associations via Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an 'User'class contains two 'Address' properties reference to 'Address' entity, and there is another class - 'Shipment' also associate with 'Address'.

How i can use fluent api on ef core to build a correct relation between entities.

```
public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Address DefaultAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual Address BillingAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Shipment
{
    public int ShipmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Address DeliveryAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not need to declare explicit configuration, the EF will do everything without any help.
I prepared a working example with and without fluent configuration, you can check it out [here](https://github.com/ikopytko/EfFluentConfigExmaple). Just switch between commits to see the  difference.
As you can notice, there is no differences in generated migration.